# I have not been able to get Electron running within Electron to run in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I have been trying to get electron up and running on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 and have been mostly unsuccessful.

(Error below from terminal)

```
nicholaos_sofocleous@DESKTOP-8U1KGF4:~/OSP/Kafmira$ npm run start
kafmira@1.0.0 start
electron.
```

(my user file path and then)`/node_modules/electron/dist/electron` exited with signal SIGTRAP

My node version is 16.13.0 and npm is 8.3.0

---

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "pack": "electron-builder -mwl"
},

(dependencies for electron in .json:)
    "electron": "^16.0.4",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",

(dev dependencies for electron in .json:)
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Having identical WSL, node & npm version, I encountered exactly the same issue.

The solution for me was to install using `npm install --platform=win32` as mentioned in this thread [Trouble starting electron in WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67175880)